# Convenience Init in Swift with less parameters

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do the following code but I get a compile error. I would like to init with no parameters because all are set to defaults values but I still need to use the designated initializer of the super class. I want to be able to call `AimNode()` for a new AimNode

```
class AimNode: SKSpriteNode {

    override init() {
        super.init(imageNamed: "aim")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass (`AimNode`) needs to call the designated initializer of your superclass (`SKSpriteNode`). The rules, as explained in the [Initializer Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_327) section of the swift programming guide are:

> To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience
>   initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation
>   calls between initializers:
>
> **Rule 1** A designated initializer must call a designated initializer
>   from its immediate superclass.
>
> **Rule 2** A convenience initializer must call another initializer from
>   the same class.
>
> **Rule 3** A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.

The appropriate designated initializer for `SKSpriteNode` is:

```
init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize)
```

So, you'll need to create an `SKTexture`, pick a color, and set the size. Luckily, that's fairly easy:

```
class AimNode: SKSpriteNode {

    // NOTE: I arbitrarily picked white for the color. I believe that's the default, but I don't know for sure.
    override init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "aim")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: texture.size())
    }

    // NOTE: You'll have to implement this too, if you don't have anything custom, you can just call the super implementation
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I thought that super.init(imageNamed: "aim") was a designated initializer.